# setting a C++ callback in C++/CLI that expects a virtual function override

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2012, c++-cli

I have working code in C++ that I am in the process of creating a wrapper in C++/CLI so I can use it in C#.

One of the methods in the C++ code is to set a function pointer. The function pointer points to a class that inherits from a virtual class.

This is the virtual class:

```
class Transmitter
{
    public:
        virtual bool Transmit(uint64_t desintation, uint8_t message) = 0;
};
```

To set the function pointer there is a function:

```
SetOutgoingFunction(Transmitter* const transmitter)
```

In C++, assuming TransmitterObject is a class that inherits and overrides the Transmit function, I set the pointer using:

```
SetOutgoingFunction(&TransmitterObject)
```

This all works fine in the realm of C++. I've done a lot of research trying to figure this wrapper, here are a few good resources: [codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-10-minutes#A8) and [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-marshal-callbacks-and-delegates-by-using-cpp-interop?view=vs-2017).

In the wrapper, I'm at point where I have a function pointer that is ready to be passed into SetOutgoingFunction. The problem is the pointer is not of the Transmitter class. CLI doesn't let me inherit from the Transmitter class since it is not a ref class.

What do I do?

I could modify the C++ code to use another type of function pointer, though I believe the way I have it set up is the proper way. If that's the case, how do I accommodate for this in the C++/CLI level?

Comment: `class Net { Net() { someTransmiter = new Pure(this); setup(someTransmiter); } someMethod(des, msg) {  Transmit?.Invoke(des, msg); }; event Transmit; } class Pure : Transmiter { Pure(Net* parent){} Transmit(des,msg) { parent->someMethod(des, msg); }}` <- it's pseudo language mix C++/C# to get the point

Comment: Write a C++ class deriving from Transmitter which wraps around the CLI delegate...

Comment: Thanks Selvin. Make it an answer if you want, it worked